# Como colocar meu site ASP.NET online

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando colocar minha aplicação ASP.NET no ar, e nunca tive contato com isso, preciso transformar meus .CSHTML em .HTML? Ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Em qual servidor você está publicando seu site?

Comment: O servidor que estou publicano é o GoDaddy

Comment: GoDaddy suporta até o MVC3. A instância que você está publicando está configurada para isso?

Comment: Não sei ao certo, porém o servidor é Linux, solicitei a migração, será que é esse o problema?

Comment: Com certeza é. Vou responder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pela extensão do arquivo posso notar que a estrutura é de um **MVC C#**, tudo que você precisa é de uma hospedagem Windows com suporte ao Net Framework.

Como nosso amigo acima disse, **.cshtml** possui não só **HTML** o mesmo é compilado no servidor e como resultado para o cliente que o acessa é a renderização.

O Envio do site é feito através de **Deploy** ou **FTP**, há outras opções mas como se trata de hospedagem é muito provável que seja essas opções, com isso será feito a compilação do projeto essa publicação é feita com o **Visual Studio**.

Mas lembre-se tenha em mente que a sua hospedagem deve ser da plataforma **Windows (IIS)**.

[Esse artigo da Microsoft deve te ajudar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update**

Com a nova versão do .NET, o .NET Core. Agora suportando múltiplas plataformas (Windows, Linux e OSx) deixarei a documentação da Microsoft auxiliando o deploy de aplicações ASP.NET em ambiente Linux.

Demais plataformas também disponíveis na documentação.

[Publish to a Linux Production Environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction)

Comment: Certo, meu servidor é Linux, nesse caso preciso trocar?

Comment: Sim, deve solicitar a migração para Windows.

Comment: Em seguida faço a transferencia FTP e ficará tudo certo? Acabei de solicitar a migração. Obrigado!

Comment: Se a fonte já estiver compilada basta enviar via FTP, caso contrário, siga os passos do artigo que anexei.

Answer (score 2):

Sabatinando o autor da pergunta, descobri que o plano de hospedagem é Linux, que (até então) não suporta um servidor que execute o ASP.NET MVC adequadamente.

[Utilize o Azure em instância gratuita](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) para hospedar seu site por enquanto.

Answer (score 1):

Danilo,

Resposta simples e directa: Não.

A extensão **.cshtml** é utilizada pelo ASP.NET View Engine **Razor**, que pode conter código para além de HTML, mas no final é renderizado HTML puro.

+info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, me ajudou, agora preciso testar e dou um feedback..